# How to input value into textbox with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

So I am trying to input a value into a text box with selenium.

Let's say I define US_T as 2.02. Thus when I `.send_keys('US_T')` the result is "US_T" is inputted into the text box. I want "2.02" to be inputted and not "US_T".

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried removing the quotes? `.send_keys(US_T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the sendkeys as below when have the value in variable.

```
element.send_keys(US_T) # <== without double quotes as it's a variable
```

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking on the hallow check mark below the down vote button, if you feel the issue is resolved.